# xpath on browser and response are different

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

When I search for an xpath in my browser after inspection it show the required result,but when I used the same xpath of my response in scrapy it should an empty list.

[image]

So when find an element on the browser, I get showing the number of satisfying element see picture for example.

Now, when I run the same xpath off my response in scrapy shell, I get an empty list,even though the response status is 200. What could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome! Insert your code as code, not as image. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You browser renders **Javascript** code and this leads to change in HTML code. So, in this case, you need to use a Javascript engine for requests in **Scrapy**. Please look at [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) to render JS and get same results as in browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you use chrome browser, if would be a a little different in some tag with you get from requests or scrapy.

Like chrome will auto add  in the html.